# Adapt Rectangle's region to a different size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

Under Windows Forms, I take a full size screenshot of a specific window that has a specific window size, I save it into a Bitmap object, then, I declared a Rectangle structure to crop a region of that Bitmap, because later I need to manipulate only a very specific part/region of the screenshot...

To make things simpler for this question, lets say the window and bitmap size is 640x480, the Rectangle's X,Y is: 436,150 and the Width,Height is: 146,170, and what I crop from the screenshot (the bitmap) is a balloon image. The window is a videogame.

The problem is that when the window size increase, the balloon image increase too, as obvious, so the x,y and width/height of my rectangle for a window size of 640x480 will not properly capture/crop the entire balloon image when the window of the game has a bigger size...

I need to know how can I calculate the x,y width/height that my rectangle should have to properly crop the balloon image when the window size changes. I need to adapt the rectangle.

So, if this is the predefined size and rectangle I have:

```
{ new Size(640, 480), new Rectangle(436, 150, 146, 170) }
```

From that, the approximated adapted values that the rectangle should have to properly crop the same equivalent area in a window size of 800x600 and 1280x768 it would be more or less these:

```
{ new Size(800, 600), new Rectangle(546, 186, 186, 212) }
{ new Size(1280, 768), new Rectangle(830, 232, 240, 274) }
```

...are just approximated values, but not perfect, because I did it manually since Im not sure which is the way to calculate and automate this math operation.

I hope my question and problem was understood. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're over-thinking it, but all you need to do is capture the percentage change between the original size and the new size (for both X and Y), and then apply that percentage to the properties of the original rectangle to get the new rectangle.

For example:

```
public static Rectangle GetNewRectangle(Size oldSize, Rectangle oldRectangle, 
    Size newSize)
{
    var percentChangeX = (double)newSize.Width / oldSize.Width;
    var percentChangeY = (double)newSize.Height / oldSize.Height;

    return new Rectangle
    {
        X = (int)(oldRectangle.X * percentChangeX),
        Y = (int)(oldRectangle.Y * percentChangeY),
        Width = (int)(oldRectangle.Width * percentChangeX),
        Height = (int)(oldRectangle.Height * percentChangeY)
    };
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Helper method to display size and rectangle properties
private static string GetDisplayValues(Size size, Rectangle rect)
{
    return $" - size: {size.Width} x {size.Height}\n" +
           $" - rect: {rect.X}, {rect.Y} : {rect.Width} x {rect.Height}\n";
}

private static void Main()
{
    var size = new Size(640, 480);
    var rect = new Rectangle(436, 150, 146, 170);                        
    Console.WriteLine($"Original:\n{GetDisplayValues(size, rect)}");

    var newSize = new Size(800, 600);
    var newRect = GetNewRectangle(size, rect, newSize);
    Console.WriteLine($"Resized:\n{GetDisplayValues(newSize, newRect)}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. For 4:3 aspect ratio works fine, like in your example, but for 16:9 aspect ratio (like 1280x768) it gives me a "X" and "Width" that does not corresponds to the area that I need to crop. that is why im over-thinking it too much, the same problem for all other answers in this question. Just one question: you think this is a logic issue with the algorithm that calculates the scale factor, or sure it probably should be a issue about how the game manages objects position/size when the aspect ratio resolution changes?

Comment: Sorry for 16:9 I meant 5:3. from 4:3 aspect ratio to 5:3

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the crop area is incorrect? If I input a new size of `1280x768`, I get a new rectangle: `872, 240 : 292 x 272`. I don't have a great way to test this in "real life", but I opened mspaint.exe and drew a colored rectangle at `0, 0 : 640 x 480`, and inside it I drew a "selection area" box of size `436, 150 : 146 x 170`. Then I selected the colored area and resized it to `1280 x 768`. The interior "selection area" was resized to the exact dimensions that were output by my code above. Can you please provide specific data that is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for clarify and test it. In my question you can see the approximated values of the values that the rectangle should have for 1280x768, relatively, but a X coordinate of 872 is much bigger than 830, and same for the Width value, so the rectangle that I get by using this generic percentage factor calculation for 1280x768 is "wrong" in the meaning that the X and Width should be smaller to crop the portion that I need, but don't worry, I assume it should be an issue about how the game handles aspect ratios / the item position/size in different aspect ratios.

Comment: That is the reason why I was very confused, over-thinking about it, because I tried to calculate the scale percentage factor in the same way of your solution and the other people's solutions but I noticed that my resulting rectangles were incorrect when applied to different aspect ratios, and then I ended asking here in StackOverflow because I thought that maybe I was calculating it bad. but your code its ok of course, now I see the problem is with the videogame itself. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

if width 640:

```
X = 436 / 640 = 0.68125 (68.125%)
W = 146 / 640 = 0.22125 (22.125%)
```

if heigth 480:

```
Y = 150 / 480 = 0.3125 (31.25%)
H = 170 / 480 = 0.3541666666666666666666666667 (35.41666666666666666666666667%)
```

Considering the size of the form as `this.Width`, and the height as `this.Height`:

```
decimal pX = 0.68125;
decimal pW = 0.22125;
decimal pY = 0.3125;
decimal pH = 0.3541666666666666666666666667;

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(this.Width * pX, this.Height * pY, this.Width * pW, this.Height * pH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a source Bitmap and a selection Rectangle inside its boundaries:

```
RectangleF SourceRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, SourceBitmap.Size);
Rectangle SelectionRect = new Rectangle([Point], [Size]);
```

When the `SourceBitmap` changes its size, the new size of the selection rectangle is calculated using the scale factor given by the relation between the old size and the new size of the `SourceBitmap`:

```
RectangleF DestinationRect = new RectangleF(Point.Empty, InflatedBitmap.Size); 

SizeF ScaleFactor = new SizeF(DestinationRect.Width / SourceRect.Width, 
                              DestinationRect.Height / SourceRect.Height);

PointF NewPosition = new PointF(SelectionRect.X * ScaleFactor.Width, SelectionRect.Y * ScaleFactor.Height);
SizeF NewSize = new SizeF(SelectionRect.Width * ScaleFactor.Width, SelectionRect.Height * ScaleFactor.Height);

RectangleF InflatedSelection = new RectangleF(NewPosition, NewSize);
```

With a SourceBitmap and a selection rectangle sized as:

```
RectangleF SourceRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, 640, 480);
RectangleF SelectionRect = new RectangleF(436, 150, 146, 170);
```

If the inflated bitmaps are sized as:

```
RectangleF DestinationRect1 = new RectangleF(0, 0, 800, 600);
RectangleF DestinationRect2 = new RectangleF(0, 0, 1280, 768);
```

The Inflated selection with a scale factor of `(1.25, 1.25)` and `(2, 1.6)` will be (rounded down):

```
RectangleF InflatedSelection1 = new RectangleF(545, 187, 182, 212);
RectangleF InflatedSelection2 = new RectangleF(872, 240, 292, 272);
```